# npm Typings not recognized command

Tags: node.js, windows, typescript, npm

So I have installed Typings globally with `npm install -g typings`

I have verified that `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm` is in my Path.

I can get it to work after a restart, but then if I close my console window and open it again the command is no longer recognized again. This is really strange. I have tried everything. I have typings installed locally on my project to, and cannot run `npm run typings <cmd>` either. This is on Windows 7 BTW.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd see this more as a windows shell issue. To see the path (which is received from windows environment every time shell is launched), type in the console 'path' and that way you can check if there's a change in path after the command stops working.

See if there's any difference between calling path from when it works and when it doesn't. Then, possibly the issue is in Windows modifying the path of all things.

Comment: I am going to choose this as the right answer. As it turns out I had it in the path for my user, but not for the system. Added it to the system path and it works as expected now I think. Thank you.